# ¿De que sirven los métodos hashCode() y equals() en un bean?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Eh visto algunos tutoriales de Hibernate con JPA, y en algunos de ellos al finalizar las clases bean escriben la etiqueta `@Overrride` y luego los métodos. Por ejemplo:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(this == obj) return true;
    if(obj == null) return false;
    if(!(obj instanceof Categoria)) return false;

    Categoria other = (Categoria) obj;

    if(codigo == null){
        if(other.codigo != null) return false;            
    }
    else return codigo.equals(other.codigo);

    return true;
}


@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 1;
    if(codigo == null)
        hash = hash * 31;
    else
        hash = hash * 31 + codigo.hashCode();

    return hash;
}
```

Más no explican el por qué, en otros casos de hecho ni siquiera lo implementan. ¿Es necesario siquiera el implementarlo, o es que acaso el proyecto debe de cumplir cierto criterio para su uso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los dos métodos son bastante importantes.

A ver, **hashCode** sirve para generar un código *único* que identifique el objeto. A simple vista no sirve de nada pero en realidad es el encargado de *colocar* el objeto como clave en un map, por ejemplo. Parece tontería, pero imagínate qué comportamiento tendría un map si todas las claves tuviesen el mismo hashcode.

El otro, **equals**. Como si nombre indica es para comparar objetos. Cómo se comparan los objetos depende de la lógica que quieres implementar. En el ejemplo que has mostrado, de la clase **Categoria**, es importante que el objeto que se compara sea de tipo *Categoria* (obvio) y que los codigos de los dos objetos sean iguales. Cómo se comparan dos beans es cosa tuya, la lógica la debes implementar tu. Este método se suele usar en los comparadores para la ordenación de listas de objetos.

Después de todo esto, está claro que no es necesario implementar estos métodos en tus clases. Si lo haces es porque tienes alguna razón de peso. Fíjate en los métodos **equals** y **hashCode** de la clase Object, ya existen y hacen su trabajo. Cuando los sobreescribes (de ahí la anotación Override) es porque necesitas un comportamiento diferente del ya existente (del de la clase Object o alguna otra clase padre).

¿Por qué la calse Categoria sobreescribe estos métodos? No lo sé con certeza pero a simple vista **equals** necesita ser sobreescrito para poder saber si dos objetos de tipo Categoria son iguales (lee el código), para ordenarlos etc. Y **hashCode** por qué esta sobreescrito no lo puedo saber pero seguro que tiene sus razones. Desconozco el comportamiento de la aplicación.

Espero haber sido de ayuda.